Authorize different multisig for mint
While investigate why the multisig for mint is failed I found out the Program Id is older then token Id. I have create new multisig and new to remove the current authorized Multisig to new one.
SPL-TOKEN command:
spl-token authorize mntXXXXXXXXXXXX mint 3uqBpdyitSBmQ3tmo1FhH2RKkHPiTbYQCm9fbb7jzet6


Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question, but the SPL Token multisig is entirely managed by the Token program. If you want to use it with your mint, be sure to create a multisig within the correct program (SPL Token or Token-2022). There's more info at https://spl.solana.com/token#multisig-usage
